# ¿Cómo importar usar un componente declarado en un modulo de nivel superior?

Tags: typescript, angular

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, necesito utilizar un componente declarado en un modulo de nivel superior, pero cuando intento importarlo me da error, este el modulo donde quiero utilzar el componente `ConfirmExitModalComponent`

**budget-table.module.ts** Modulo de nivel inferior

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        Md2Module,
        PipesModule,
        TextMaskModule,
        DirectivasModule,
        ComponentesModule,  // <- Esto produce el error de mas abajo
        BlockUIModule,
        DndModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    declarations: [
        BudgetTableComponent,
        BudgetTableNodeComponent,
        BudgetAddNodeComponent,
        BudgetRemoveNodeComponent,
        BudgetSaveModalComponent,
        FormulaItemModalComponent,
        BudgetAddItemComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        BudgetTableComponent,
        BudgetTableNodeComponent,
        BudgetAddNodeComponent,
        BudgetRemoveNodeComponent,
        BudgetSaveModalComponent,
        FormulaItemModalComponent,
        BudgetAddItemComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        BudgetDataService
    ]
})
export class BudgetTableModule {}
```

**componentes.module.ts** modulo padre que contiene el componente que necesito

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // Quitado varios import para que no se haga tan estenso el codigo
        BudgetTableModule,  // modulo hijo en el que estoy trabajando
        WorkPlanTableModule,
        ViewCertificateModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        TimelineComponent,
        PlanTrabajoCardComponent,
        PlantillasTreeComponent,
        DialogEventComponent,
        ConfirmExitModalComponent,  //componente que necesito importar en BudgetTableModule
    ],
    exports: [
        TimelineComponent,
        PlanTrabajoCardComponent,
        PlantillasTreeComponent,
        DialogEventComponent,
        ConfirmExitModalComponent,
        ViewCertificateModule,
        BudgetTableModule

    ],
    entryComponents: [
        BlockTemplateComponent,
    ],
    providers: [],
})
export class ComponentesModule {}
```

Si intento importar el modulo `ComponentesModule` dentro de `BudgetTableModule` me produce el siguiente error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module
>   'BudgetTableModule'

Y a nivel de directorio y carpeta estan organizados

```
/componentes
   /budget-table
       budget-table.module.ts
       etc...
   /confirm-exit-modal
       confirm-exit-modal.component.ts
       ...
   componentes.module.ts
```

La solución sencilla seria importar `ConfirmExitModalComponent` en `BudgetTableModule`pero no quiero hacer ello porque son cosas diferentes, y si lo importo en ambos me dará error de que se declaro en 2 módulos, así que de momento no se que hacer.

Extra angular me estas avisando que tengo definida una dependencia circular

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\componentes\componentes.module.ts ->
>   src\app\componentes\budget-table\budget-table.module.ts ->
>   src\app\componentes\componentes.module.ts

Comment: Lo que esta pasando es que importas un module dentro de otro y se genera un bucle, podrías crear un modulo que maneje tus componentes genéricos que tenga la única finalidad de agruparlos a todos y servir para su importación, me explico? Y así usar ese 3er modulo, para adquirir los componentes en los otros dos.

Comment: Claro, probare eso, en realidad El modulo agrupador es `ComponentesModule` despues hay otro modulos aparte de el que me esta causando conflicto, en fin tendre que agregar otro modulo mas :S

Comment: Hola, por la forma de como agrupas muchos componentes en modules, creo que no la forma mas óptima, te paso una guía de buenas practicas  oficial de Angular para estructurar bien tu proyecto: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#application-structure-and-ngmodules